The problem of not uploading files larger than 2MB using PHP persists despite modifying the php.ini file to allow uploading files larger than 2MB
I am facing a major problem with my PHP script, which is supposed to be able to upload files to the server with a size exceeding 2MB. The script works well when setting the allowed file size to 1MB, but when setting the file size to 2MB, the script does not work at all. It saves the rest of the data in the form without paying attention to the file, and the script does not consider the restrictions that should be applied, such as exiting the script and displaying an error message that the file size is larger than 2MB.
I have edited the restrictions in the php.ini file as follows:
upload_max_filesize = 3M
post_max_size = 8M
So please help me to solve the problem.
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){   
  $allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf']; // Define your allowed file types
  $uploadedFile = $_FILES['file'];
  $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $filetempname = $uploadedFile['tmp_name'];
  $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
  $filestype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
  $fileExtension = explode('.',$fileName);
  $fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileExtension));
  $fileInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $mime = finfo_file($fileInfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
  if (!in_array($fileExtension, $allowedExtensions) || !in_array($mime, ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf'])) {
    echo '<script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            toastr.error("Invalid file type or extension");
        }) 
      </script>';
     exit();
     }
  if ($filesize > 2 * 1024 * 1024) {
    echo '<script> 
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                toastr.error("File size should be less than 2MB");
            }) 
          </script>';
    exit();
   }
  finfo_close($fileInfo);
  $uniqueFilename = uniqid() . '_' . random_string(20) . '.' . $fileExtension;
  $uploadPath = 'uploads/' . $uniqueFilename;
  move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile['tmp_name'], $uploadPath);
  
  else {
  $uploadPath="";
  $stmt=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO jentress_erp (date, jnum, description, company,j_type, token_serial,position) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $test_date, $entry_num, $descrip, $company,$j_type,$serial,$uploadPath);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();       
  echo '<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
      toastr.success("1 new file added");
   }) 
   </script>';

  }
  
}
 


There is more than one php.ini in your installation usually - one for web and one for command-line PHP. Did you definitely modify the right one? Did you restart the webserver after modifying it?

P.S. upload_max_filesize = 3M is clearly 3 MB, not 2MB as stated in your question. So even if you applied it correctly, clearly it would not cause an error for a file of 2MB size

@ADyson Yes, I have modified the size in more than one php.ini file within the installation file, and the problem still exists. The strange thing is that once a file larger than 2mb is uploaded, the restrictions in the code are not applied at all, and the rest of the code is executed completely, with the file not being uploaded and the error message not being shown that the file It is larger than what is allowed, but when a condition is made that a file larger than 1MB will not be uploaded, the full conditions are implemented in the code, an error message is shown, and the code exits.

If the file exceeds the upload limit, then the file size will be set to zero. Here is what you should be checking for: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Try to change php.ini file inside apache folder And Set :
upload_max_filesize = 1024M && post_max_size = 8M
